# CSS PHP error div container

Tags: php, html, css, position

I would like to know how I can realise the following idea:

I have a registration form. In case of a PHP error message, I would like to display a div beside each input field where the specific error message takes place. So at the moment I have the CSS problem to set that div in front of all other divs. So I started looking at Z-index, but for some reason that does not work.

I have in my css:

```
#form-error{
  background-color: #f23;
  z-index:1;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

And in the HTML:

```
<?php if(isset($errors)):?>
  <?php foreach($errors as $error):?>
    <div id="form-error">
    <?php echo $error;?>
    </div>
  <?php endforeach;?>
<?php endif;?>
```

So I'm very interested in ideas on how to solve this.

Thanks a lot.

UPDATE

with the help of the user deflect i recognized that i should add a position statement. i did so. now i have all error messages listed down.

this user mentioned that it would be better to reoganize my php logic to have one specific errormessage that i just have to add into a box of class form-error beside the input field. this is not the problem. i can get each errormessage from an array. my problem is, how to realize that i have these boxes beside the input fields.

Comment: IDs must be unique. Use a CSS class name in this case, not an ID.

Comment: can't remember well, but I think you need to have absolute/relative/fixed positon elements. Try and add a prosition: rule.

Answer (score 4):

In order for z-index to work, you need to add in your css either `position:relative;`, `position:absolute;`, or `position:fixed;`.

I don't know what else might be the issue, but I would start by adding that to your CSS, like so:

```
#form-error{ 
    position: relative;
    background-color: #f23; 
    z-index:1;  
    width: 200px; 
    height: 50px; 
}
```

Comment: okay, thanks so far. one problem solved. the next is how to realise that these divs will be placed beside the input fields?

Comment: Instead of adding all your errors at once, at the end, I would actually try moving your PHP logic into the form itself, so that the divs are placed next to the appropriate input item.  Then, you could reposition them if you needed to.  (Caveat: I'm not experienced with PHP)

Comment: this should not be the problem. i have an array in which i can select each specific error message so that i just need to add the output into the specific box. the funny thing about that is that i`m not experienced with CSS and would like to know on how to realise that i have a box beside each field :)

Comment: @bonny how do you realize there is a box? then add a css style for the box, like `border: 1px solid red;` then you will see a box with a red border.